# Site name with html tag

Tags: 7

How can I have the site name with a span html tag without hard-coding it in a template? [ex. `Good<span>4</span>You`]

Comment: You want the site name so that you can use it in content? You say, "without hard-coding it in a template"; do you want to use it, for example, within your node body (From the admin interface)?

Comment: I've got the site name on the header and that's all. I just want to set a different color for just one word of my site name. Check the example of my question that I just edited. So if my website's site name was Good4You, I'd like to have a red colored "4" while the rest of the site name would be green.

Comment: You have to use JavaScript if you don't want to modify a template file.  Can I ask why you don't want to modify it?

Comment: Maybe the best way is to use a template file after all. I was just curious if there is a "cleaner" way to achieve this throughout drupal interface after installing a module or smth. :) thanks alot @ChrisRockwell

Comment: I think the Drupal way would be to just modify html.tpl.php.

Comment: @ChrisRockwell  $site_name is normally in page.tpl.php via `template_preprocess_page()`

Answer (score 2):

Its not at all difficult. I tried it in Drupal 7.22

`Goto Configuration` => `Site Information` => `Site Name` =>

```
My Site <span class="dummy-class">This is my new website</span>
```

Add whatever tags you like to have. But remember `site title` itself is already inside `<span>` tag, which means you have some restriction *(Span tag is not container)*.

*This is what it looks when I inspect it using firebug in mozilla.*
[image]

In your case, its `Good<span>4</span>You`. Just by using `css` you can do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to add a block via admin/structure/block/add and create the exact markup you want.

Then add the block to the region you want (probably **Header**), style, disable site name and site slogan in your theme settings, and go on your way.

Answer (score 0):

And here comes the template way :), place in template.php in your theme and change MYTHEME to the machine name of your theme.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['site_name'] = 'Good<span>4</span>You';
}
```